# Getting error in PHP, foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string given

Tags: php, wordpress-plugin-creation

Getting that error, while developing the plugin by following a youtube video series.

```
$options = get_option('vaishnavi_plugin_cpt');
foreach (  ($options) as $option) {
    $this->custom_post_types[] = array(
    'post_type'             => $option['post_type'],
    'name'                  => $option['plural_name'],
    'singular_name'         => $option['singular_name'],
    'menu_name'             => $option['plural_name']
  )
}
```

After looking in on how to solve this issue, I have just added a check `if(is_array($options))`
above the foreach, the error got resolved but I am not getting the desired o/p.

Also, when I `var_dump($options)`, it gives me `string(0) ""`.

When I checked the get_option wp method, it says the following

When adding options like this: `add_option( 'my_option_name', 'value' )` and then retrieving them with `get_option( 'my_option_name' )`, the returned values will be:

```
false returns string(0) ""
true returns string(1) "1"
0 returns string(1) "0"
1 returns string(1) "1"
'0' returns string(1) "0"
'1' returns string(1) "1"
null returns string(0) ""
```

Can any one please explain on why it is not showing me the array, or any possible solution.

Comment: You are setting a value and then retrieving it.  What array are you expecting?

Comment: `when I var_dump($options), it gives me string(0) "".`...this suggests that no value was set for this option when you tried to retrieve it. Presumably then, your code has never previously set this option, and so there is nothing to retrieve. If you disagree, please provide a [mre] of the scenario which demonstrates it. But it would be a clear and obvious bug in wordpress I think, if it failed to retrieve an option that was previously set correctly. Therefore I would think it's far more likely that the issue is simply that you haven't used add_option to set any such option in your application.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to use the option as an array, you will need to do something like:

```
add_option( 'vaishnavi_plugin_cpt', json_encode([
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2'
]) );
```

which creates your option and encodes an array as a JSON string, passing it as the option. Then you can use it like

```
$rawOptions = json_decode(get_option('vaishnavi_plugin_cpt'));
$options = (is_array($rawOptions) ? $rawOptions : [$rawOptions]);
foreach (  ($options) as $option) {
    $this->custom_post_types[] = array(
    'post_type'             => $option['post_type'],
    'name'                  => $option['plural_name'],
    'singular_name'         => $option['singular_name'],
    'menu_name'             => $option['plural_name']
  )
}
```

Which retrieves the option, decrypts it and, if it does not happen to be an array, converts it into an array.